# Можно ли отказаться от try-with-resources?

Tags: java, try-catch

Предисловие: для моков статических методов в Mockito существует интерфейс `MockedStatic`, наследующийся от `AutoClosable`. Соответственно, его обычно использьзуют вот так:

```
try (MockedStatic<SomeUtil> staticMockedSomeUtil = new MyClass()) {
    // некоторая логика
}
```

Я хочу заметить, что методы `MockedStatic` не выбрасывают проверяемых исключений, в том числе и метод `close()`.

В связи с этим, мне приходит мысль отказаться от использования блока `try-with-resources` и сделать примерно вот такую утилиту, которую я буду использовать в тестах:

```
public class TestUtil {

    private final List<MockedStatic<?>> activeResources = new ArrayList<>();

    public <T> MockedStatic<T> mock(Class<T> clazz) {
        MockedStatic<T> mockedClass = MockedStatic.mockStatic(clazz);
        activeResources.add(mockedClass);
        return mockedClass;
    }

    public void closeAll() {
        activeResources.forEach(resource -> resource.close());
    }
}
```

Во-первых в тестах можно будет отказаться от использования `try-with-resources`, код станет чище. Во-вторых я хочу написать единый утильный класс для тестирования, которым будет пользоваться вся команда.

Таким образом, вопрос следующий: а нужен ли мне `try-with-resources`, если класс для доступа к ресурсу не бросает проверяемых исключений ни при работе, ни при закрытии?

Comment: почему акцент на проверяемые исключения? а непроверяемые?

Comment: Так исключения могут выбрасываться в другом месте кода. А ресурсы все равно освобождать нужно.

Comment: @IR42 ну их обычно с помощью try...catch не ловят

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой вопрос можно ответить, если посмотреть, во что компилируется `try-with-resources`.

Вот [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/260417/) есть пример того, как такой код:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    baos.flush();
}
```

компилируется вот в такой:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Throwable var2 = null;
try {
    baos.flush();
} catch (Throwable var11) {
    var2 = var11;
    throw var11;
} finally {
    if (baos != null) {
        if (var2 != null) {
            try {
                baos.close();
            } catch (Throwable var10) {
                var2.addSuppressed(var10);
            }
        } else {
            baos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Можно видеть, что ничего сверхъестественного под капотом не происходит. Конкретно в моём случае с `MockedStatic` можно обойтись без `try-with-resources`, разумеется, если обеспечить надёжный механизм закрытия.

Answer (score 1):

можно (особенно в тестах).

[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) это "синтактический сахар", который упрощает работу с `AutoClosable` автоматически вызывая `close()`.

Если Вы предпочитаете другой (достаточно надежный) способ освобождения ресурсов (вызова `close()`), то вполне можете обойтись без автоматического освобождения.